# Writing defaultdict to CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a `defaultdict` being written to file like this:

```
writer = csv.writer(open(locationToSaveFile, 'wb+'))    
for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    writer.writerow([k ,v])
```

I then have this horribly convoluted text to read it back in:

```
myDict = defaultdict(list) 
with open(fileLocation, 'rb') as test:
    reader = csv.DictReader(test, ['processedText', 'date'])

    for line in reader:
        myDict[line['processedText']].append(line['date'])

textDict = defaultdict(list) 

for processedText, date in myDict.items():
    actual_list = ast.literal_eval(date[0])
    for a in actual_list:
        textDict[processedText].append(a)

for processedText, date in textDict.items():
```

Obviously this looks very wasteful (and looks horrible!) but I don't know how else to import the `defaultdict`.

When opening it with the `reader =` and `for line in reader` lines it creates a list within a list. The only way out of this is to use `ast` to convert it.

Could somebody advise me how to tidy this up?

Note: I'm *very* unfamiliar with Python

Answer (score 4):

`csv` is meant to store rows of data, not a simple dictionary. You can use [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for that:

```
import json

# writing
json.dump(yourdict, open(filename, 'w'))

# reading
yourdict = json.load(open(filename))
```

Comment: How do I read it back from JSON. I can write it using json.dump(filelocation, defaultdict). But how do I import it again?

Comment: Andrew, use json.load(filelike_object)

Answer (score 0):

Your dict's values are lists. A possible approach is to expand those lists into csv columns, producing a file where the number of columns varies from row to row:

```
#writing
with open(locationToSaveFile, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)    
    for k,v in mydict.iteritems():
        writer.writerow([k] + v)

#reading
with open(locationToSaveFile, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)    
    mydict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for row in reader:
        mydict[row[0]] = row[1:]
```